# wget, recursively download all jpegs works only on website homepage

Tags: web-scraping, jpeg, wget

I'm using [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) to download all jpegs from a website.

I searched a lot and this should be the way:

```
wget -r -nd -A jpg  "http://www.hotelninfea.com"
```

This should recursively `-r` download files jpegs `-A jpg` and store all files in a single directory, without recreating website directory tree `-nd`

Running this command downloads only the jpegs from the homepage of the website, not the whole jpegs of all the website.

I know that a jpeg file could have different extensions (jpg, jpeg) and so on, but this is not the case, also there aren't any robots.txt restrictions acting.

If I remove the filter from the previous command, it works as expected

```
wget -r -nd "http://www.hotelninfea.com"
```

This is happening on Lubuntu 16.04 64bit, wget 1.17.1

Is this a bug or I am misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ewcz anwer pointed me to the right way, the `--accept acclist` parameter has a dual role, it define the rules of file saving and the rules of following links.

Reading deeply [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Types-of-Files) I found this

> If ‘--adjust-extension’ was specified, the local filename might have ‘.html’ appended to it. If Wget is invoked with ‘-E -A.php’, a filename such as ‘index.php’ will match be accepted, but upon download will be named ‘index.php.html’, which no longer matches, and so the file will be deleted.

So you can do this

```
wget -r -nd -E -A jpg,php,asp "http://www.hotelninfea.com"
```

But of course a webmaster could have been using [custom extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php)

So I think that the most robust solution would be a bash script, something 
like

```bash
WEBSITE="http://www.hotelninfea.com"
DEST_DIR="."

image_urls=`wget -nd --spider -r "$WEBSITE" 2>&1 | grep '^--' | awk '{ print $3 }' | grep -i '\.\(jpeg\|jpg\)'`

for image_url in $image_urls; do
  DESTFILE="$DEST_DIR/$RANDOM.jpg"
  wget "$image_url" -O "$DESTFILE"
done
```

`--spider` wget will not download the pages, just check that they are there
`$RANDOM` asks a random number to the operating system

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is happening because the main page you mention contains links to the other pages in the form `http://.../something.php`, i.e., there is an explicit extension. Then the option `-A jpeg` has the "side-effect" of removing those pages from the traversal process.

Perhaps a bit dirty workaround in this particular case would be something like this:

```
wget -r -nd -A jpg,jpeg,php  "http://www.hotelninfea.com" && rm -f *.php
```

i.e., to download only the necessary extra pages and then delete them if `wget` successfully terminates.